# How to make sure shdfs Centralized Cache is working

Tags: caching, hadoop

I just wonder if `hdfs dfs copyToLocal <file1> <file2>` is a good way to test that the hdfs read caching is configured properly.

In my experiment, I did not see reasonable improvement of copying out a 1gb `<file1>` to a local directory, after the directory of `<file1>` is added to the hdfs cache. The time to complete the copy is about 17sec, before and after `<file1>` is added to the cache.

`<file1>` is verified to be added to the cache via `listDirective -stats` command.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Some words are dropped after the submission of the question. Try again. In my experiment, I did not see reasonable improvement of copying out a 1gb file to a local directory, after the directory is added to the hdfs cache. The time to complete the copy is about 17sec, before and after the file is added to the cache. 

The file is verified to be added to the cache via listDirective -stats command.

Answer (score 0):

Including the output of hdfs dfsadmin -report would be useful.

Increasing the ulimit and setting dfs.datanode.max.locked.memory

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/CentralizedCacheManagement.html